# Laravel Auth::check() is always failing

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a ReactJS App with a  **Laravel 8.9.0** backend api.  I am using the Laravel Auth functionality that creates a token and passes it to my front end app.  I am able to log-in and create a token properly with a hash password etc.  What I am not able to do is "Check Login" with the `is_login` method shown below in the controller.  The `Auth::check()` is always failing, what am I doing wrong?  Below are my controllers and routes api.php file.  Please help!

**Login Controller:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\Users;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request) {

        $login = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required:string',
            'password' => 'required:string'
        ]);

        if(!Auth::attempt($login)) {
            return response([
                'message' => 'Invalid Credentials'
            ]);
        }

        $accessToken = Auth::user()
                    ->createToken('authToken')
                    ->accessToken;
        
        return response([
           'user' => Auth::user(),
           'access_token' => $accessToken 
        ]);
    }

    public function is_login()
    {
        $is_login = false;
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $is_login = true;
        }
        return response()->json(['is_login' => $is_login]);
    }
}
```

**Routes api.php**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::post('/login', 'App\Http\Controllers\LoginController@login');
Route::get('/login-check', 'App\Http\Controllers\LoginController@is_login');
```

Comment: Does `Auth::guard('api')->check()` works? Are you passing the token in the header?

Comment: @nakov It also returns false and I am not passing the token into the header no, but I figured that the backend should automatically work.

Comment: Well, how will the backend know that it is a valid user that makes the request? And which user is it? That's why you create the token at the end of the day. The backend knows which user is it if you use the session driver.

Comment: Yes you are right I am sharing my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this problem you must pass the token into the header with every request:

In my ReactJS I did this on `componentDidMount()`

```
    componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const config = {
                headers: { 
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${mytoken}`
                }
            };
            
            
            axios.get('/api/login-check',
                { key: "value" },
                { headers: config }
            ).then(
                console.log('succ')
            ).catch(
                console.log('err')
            );


        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Error in submission', err)
        }
    }
```

and in my api I added the middleware to the check:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/login-check', 'App\Http\Controllers\LoginController@is_login');
```